# Segmentation Fault in a C function

Tags: c, arrays, function, memory

I hope you have spent beautiful Christmas holidays. I am studying for an exam and I have a problem with my project in ANSI C. My code works but not always, it's strange because for some input values it works for other not. I have two arrays, A and B, that must be different in size and I have to write a function that do the mathematical union of the two arrays in another array. If there are elements of the same value I have to insert in the new array only one. I write all the code (I also post a question here because I had some problems with the union) but it does not work always. Gcc compile and I execute but it's not correct. I debugged with gdb and it said

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400d1c in unionearraycrescente (a=0x7fffffffdd50, indice_m=4, 
b=0x7fff00000005, indice_n=5, minimo=6, indiceMinimo=22)
at array.c:152
152                 if(b[i]==c[j])
```

And this is the code near the problem

```
int arrayun(int a[], int index_m, int b[], int index_n, int minimum, int indexMinimum) 
{

    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int found; 
    int lenc=0; 
    int c[lenc]; 
    for(i=0;i<index_m;i++){

        found = 0; 
        for(j=0; j<i && !found;j++)
            if(a[i]==c[j])
                found = 1;
        if(!found) 
            c[lenc++] = a[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<index_n;i++){
        found=0;
        for(j=0;j<i && !found;j++)
            {
            if(b[i]==c[j]) //debug gbd problem - segfault
            found = 1;
            }
        if(!found)
            c[lenc++] = b[i];
    }
```

I am Italian so the comments are in my language, if you have any problems I will translate the comments. I want only to resolve this memory error. Thank you.

I follow some of your advices and in that part of code it works, I changed all the variables with index_m and I don't receive segfault but after the union I use the selection sort to sort in ascending order and it return me not the right values but in the first position negative values.

```
int arrayun (int a[], int index_m, int b[], int index_n, int minimum, int indexMinimum) 
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int found;
    int lenc; 
    int c[index_m]; 
    for(i=0;i<index_m;i++){

        found = 0;
        for(j=0; j<i && !found;j++)
            if(a[i]==c[j]) 

                found = 1; //setta trovato = 1
        if(!found) 
            c[index_m++] = a[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<index_n;i++){ //index_m or index_n?
        found=0;
        for(j=0;j<i && !found;j++)
            {
            if(b[i]==c[j]) //debug gbd problem - segfault - SOLVED but
            found = 1;
            }
        if(!found)
            c[index_m++] = b[i];
    }


    for (i=0; i<index_m-1;i++)
    {
        minimum=c[i];
        indexMinimum=i;

        for (j=i+1;j<index_m; j++)
        {
            if (c[j]<minimum)
            {
                minimum=c[j];
                indiexMinimum=j;
            }
        }
        c[indexMinimum]=c[i];
        c[i]=minimum;
    }


   for(i=0;i<index_m;i++)
        printf("Element %d\n",c[i]);
    return c[index_m]; //I think here it's wrong
}
```

Comment: int c[lenc]; means in your program it is c[0]. And if you try for b[i]==c[i] where i>0 means its a segmentation fault only.

Comment: I like the code that I wrote (I found it) so please if you can help me with this.

Comment: `trovato = 1;`, do you mean `found = 1;`?

Comment: @SridharDD So how I have to modify lenc?

Comment: Yes, I mean found = 1. I forget to modify.

Comment: @Francesco , You are creating a 0 length array. You can't store anything in it. There is no memory reserved for it. This explains the seg fault. Give `c` some reasonable size and try the program

Comment: @Francesco You can initialize like c[index_m].

Comment: I followed your advices. It works. Thank you, you are so kindly. God bless all of you. Have nice days.

Answer (score 2):

```
int c[lenc]; means in your program it is c[0]
```

and you are allocating **ZERO Memory for the array**.

And if you try for `b[i]==c[i] where i>=0 means its a segmentation fault only`.

Instead you can initialize like,

```
c[index_m];
```

Comment: In that part of code it works, I changed all the variables with index_m and I don't receive segfault but after the union I use the selection sort to sort in ascending order and it return me not the right value. I will add the problem in my question.

Comment: Why you changed this c[index_m++]? Now to you are doing same thing again by initializing with c[indem_m++] and using c[index_m++] will cause segmentation fault. Replace c[index_m++] with c[lenc++] Hope this may be the problem. If not use a good debugger to solve the issue.

Comment: I followed your advices. It works. Thank you, you are so kindly. God bless all of you. Have nice days.

Answer (score 1):

```
int lenc=0;
int c[lenc];
```

this is array of 0 length.and in loop you are trying to access c[1],c[2]... etc.

To cure this problem you can pass length of the bigger array

```
int unionearraycrescente (int a[], int index_m, int b[], int index_n,int len, int minimum, int indexMinimum)

and you can then initialize like
int c[len];
```

Comment: `//not valid in c` .What?

Comment: @CoolGuy we can't initialize in ansi c like this.right?

Comment: Yeah. It is not valid in ANSI c,but it is in newer standards. You can't say that you can't use it in the C programming language

Comment: Or just use `//not valid in ANSI c` instead of that comment.

Comment: Why someone is downvoting ??